# Trying to use auto margin-left/right: auto place image at the left hand side

Tags: css

Positioning my image explicitly using left: places it correctly, however when I removed left: and replaced it instead with margin-left: auto and margin-right: auto it got positioned on the left hand side. What have I done wrong?

```
<body>
    <div id = "main_header" href="http://xxx" >
        <img id = "logo" src="logo.png"/>
        <h1 id = "main_title">Title</h1>
    </div>


    body {
        position:relative;
        background-image: url("large_background.png");
        font-family: Helvetica; 
        margin: 0;              /* Amount of negative space around the outside of the body */
        padding: 0;             /* Amount of negative space around the inside of the body */
    }

    #main_header {
        position: relative;
    }


    #logo {
        position:absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 140px;
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
    }
```

Comment: Yes it it: <img id = "logo" src= ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image has the css set to position absolute.
Using this attribute, your "logo" will be positionated relative to the div "main_header", because this is set to position:relative.
That's why margins don't works. With position:absolute only "left", "top", and others will work.

To use Margin, you should remove the position attribute.

Comment: To resolve, delete the position:absolute of the img, and put the image inside of a div, ex: <div id = "logo"><img  src="logo.png"/></div>
Than, set margin:0 auto to this div